# Intent query/filter seems buggy

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

TL:DR; version:

- 2k lines in manifest, 4 intentfilter for one activity, 50 mimeTypes, 400 fileExtensions
- app opens every file related to printing via action SEND (from txt to xls, tiff, vcs, ...)
- but NO unprintable files (videos, apk and so on)
- when opening a SINGLE file from a 3rd party explorer the filter works right
- when doing the same for MULTIPLE files (SEND_MULTIPLE), the filter works right if ONE file matches

**Problem:**

When using

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveList = ctx.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

In the app for a Uri wich contains a Video (i.e., non-printable) my app IS offered, even if the intent filter in the manifest should filter that OUT. (As it does when opening a file from a 3rd party app.)

See docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY

...so the manifest has to be right, but the query doesn't seem to filter... =/

Any Advices or ideas?